# How to save data as a non-root user in a container？

Tags: docker

I try to use docker in the cluster of my school.And I have add my accout into docker group.I run the container by：`docker run -it -v ~/documents:/home/fenics/shared fenicsdrl1 /bin/bash`.But I was told that I don't have the permissions when I tried to write my data into a file.Here are my error message：
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: log/tensorboard/_model=PPO2_default_Mlp1_step_1_episode_18CPU_time=2022-10-27_06_56_28_1; Permission denied`

I tried to run this container by：`docker run -it -v ~/documents:/home/fenics/shared fenicsdrl1 /bin/bash --privileged=true` and `docker run -it --user==$UID:$(id -g $USER) -v ~/documents:/home/fenics/shared fenicsdrl1 /bin/bash`.But it didn't work.

Any advises would be appreciated:).

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's in your image?  It looks like you're trying to run an interactive bash shell, but then you get a Python exception; what code causes this?  What (numeric) user is the container running as, and what (numeric) user owns the host directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have write permission in ~/documents folder, you need create new folder with full permission and replace ~/documents by that new folder.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the sudo command?

Comment: I can’t use the sudo command because I don't have the permission:(

Comment: If there is a way to solve this problem permanently I will try to apply to administer.

Comment: Oh，I understand your idea. I found I can use sudo command without password.Thank you very much.

Comment: well if that helped you solve the issue then am glad I could help :)